# How to make expand collaspe and expand to move to top like anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have zero knowledge in JS or JQuery and am learning to do so

I am trying to update my code that will help me do the following

I am trying to achieve the following points, at once :

1. When you click on the anchor link, the page moves the content to the top of the page.
2. When you click on the expand for a object, the others collapses

I have finally compiled this code here

[**Click here to view the link**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMYLNb)

```
Please help me in achieving both the points
```

Thanks for your efforts

Comment: You can use what you already have to accomplish what you want. Can you fiddle it?

Comment: tried to do that, don't know how to get that on fiddle

Comment: What do you mean when you say: ... _page moves the content to the top of the page_? could you explain a bit more, not sure I understand

Comment: I can answer question 2 easily , but I want to see if I can help you with question 1, as to not give a half answer

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Hi all, the first part of the question need to be like this link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_a_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your `collapseExpandLink` function like this. I added a For Loop which will loop through all the links and close them all. As for the scrolling, I borrowed a bit of code from user MSolanki's answer. Said method used is [ScrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxVWoZ)

```
function collapseExpandLink(evt) {
  if (this.collapseDiv.style.display == '') {    
    this.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling.style.display = 'none';
    this.firstChild.nodeValue = 'expand';    
  } else {
    //Close all DIVs    
    for(var i = 0;i < collapseLinks.length;i++){
      collapseLinks[i].parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling.style.display = 'none';
    }
    this.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling.style.display = '';
    this.firstChild.nodeValue = 'collapse';
    //Scroll page to current clicked link
    this.scrollIntoView();
  }

  if (evt && evt.preventDefault) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
  return false;
}
```

[UPDATED]

You need to add your image with javascript inside the function you use to create all collapsible links.

[Updated Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVYJBE)

```
function createCollapseLink(element, siblingContainer, index) {
  var span;
  //Create an image element
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  //Provide image src url
  img.src = "http://www.webster.ch/_resources/images/down-arrow.png";
  //Add classname
  img.className = "myImg"
  if (document.createElement && (span = document.createElement('span'))) {
    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(String.fromCharCode(160)));
    var link = document.createElement('a');    
    link.collapseDiv = siblingContainer;
    link.href = '#';
    //Wrapping image inside all links
    link.appendChild(img);
    link.onclick = collapseExpandLink;
    collapseLinks[index] = link;
    span.appendChild(link);
    element.appendChild(span);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much IndieRock, this works perfectly :)

Comment: Hey Indierok, is it possible to have the image instead of the word Chapter and expand/collaspe. SO when you click on the image, it acts like a expand and collapse?

Comment: Can't you wrap your image with the `<a>` link?

Comment: tried with that, issue. I apologise, fairly new to jquery :(

Comment: no problem, I need to finish something quick, but I'll take a look in a few minutes. basically you need to find a way to add an image in javascript and wrap the link around it from your createlink function

Comment: thank you IndieRok. I actually tried adding directly to the HTML, so I was not getting it through that way

Comment: @user1753985 check my updated answer. I'll let you continue from that, I'm sure you will be ok

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding the 1st point you have specified anchor tag with "#" as href so clicking on anchor tag is moving up. so onclick of anchor tag u can return false. so that it wont go up.

Comment: actually OP wants the page to scroll to the current clicked link

Comment: Yes exactly Indie Rok

Comment: ya got it.... so mention the particular div id in href so it will move to that place ex:href="#id" so clicking on anchor tag will take you to the div which you mention in href

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code I have created for you. I have changed structure little bit to wrap H1 and p tags in a div.

Please have a look here on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtechdev/gumk1uro/)

Here is working code. I haven't spend time optimizing it but at least will get you going.

```
$(function() {
  $("div > p").hide();
  $("h1").each(function() {
    var $a = $("<a href='javascript:{}'>Expand</a>")
    $a.insertAfter($(this));
    $a.click(function() {
      var text = $(this).text();

      if (text.toLowerCase() == "expand") {
                $div =  $(this).parent();
        $p = $div.find("p");
        $p.show();
        $(this).text("Collapse");

        $(this).parent().get(0).scrollIntoView();

        var siblings = $div.siblings()
        siblings.find("p").hide();
        siblings.find("a").text("Expand");
      }else
      {
            $(this).text("Expand");
          $(this).parent().find("p").hide();
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort MSolanki, this works too :)